# Fix tslint issue on Quasar component (getting the value from the Vuex Store)

Tags: typescript, vuex, tslint, quasar-framework, vue-composition-api

At **Quasar**, I am using `root.$store.getters` to get the values from the Vuex Store. but as **Quasar** is based on typescript, I got the tslint issue like the following image.
[image: tslint issue]

please help me how I fix the above tslint issue.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

by using [vuex-composition-helpers](https://github.com/greenpress/vuex-composition-helpers), I fixed the above issues.
my working code like the following.

[image]

Regards